# How to show download image when user click on edit button in GridView

Tags: javascript, asp.net, gridview

I have a edit link with class "icon-edit" from twitter-bootstrap. I want to show downloading image when user click on this button in javascript. I did like this:

```
var editLink = $('.icon-edit');
   editLink.onclick = function () {
        document.getElementById("editLoading").style.visibility = "visible";
   }
```

It doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the proper CSS style you need to change is `display` to have the value "block" (or "inline").

In addition, you shouldn't/can't mix jQuery and Javascript like that. If you work with a jQuery object (using `$("")`), then you should use jQuery methods. If you want to use plain Javascript, then you can use Javascript methods.

In your case, you select an element by class, with jQuery. But then you attempt to bind the `onclick` handler to the selected element with `.onclick`, which is plain Javascript.

You should use:

```
$(".icon-edit").on("click", function () {
    $("#editLoading").show();    // Basically the same as: $("#editLoading").css("display", "block");
});
```

Instead of saying "It doesn't work.", you should explain what's happening. Did you check your browser's console? Do you get error messages? Does something freeze? Did you attempt to debug in any way, even by placing `alert` statements in places to see how far the code gets?